# Stopping files from always opening in offline mode in SharePoint 2010

Tags: offline-sync

I have users who share files.  Every time they open a file it automatically opens in offline mode and does not update.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Is it happening for all the users or some? Does it happen for all documents or specific ones? What about new documents?

Comment: Seems to be happening with one specific user and for mostly excel documents

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with Office Document Cache, maybe a corruption

Clear the Office Document Cache for that user on the system that they are having the issue by:

- Go to Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft Office -> Microsoft Office 2010 Tools
- Run the ‘Microsoft Office 2010 Upload Center’
- Under Settings, click on Delete cached files